# ie9 -ms-transform being ignored

Tags: html, css

Can anybody please shine any light on why the following -ms- line of CSS is being ignored by IE9?

It doesn't appear on firebug light at all and is driving us nuts!

```
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(50%);
```

any advice would be great.  thanks

Comment: Works fine for me. One thing to check: Try opening developer tools, and see if you can determine the document mode that IE is using. There are certain scenarios in which IE might think to try using document mode 7 or 8, and you can override those on a per-case basis.

Comment: IE9 should work with a prefixed transform and the rule does look valid (though it could be simplified to `transform: translate(-50%, 50%)`.  There are a few quirks about the `transform` property on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) that you may be running into.  Can you put up an example so we can see exactly what's causing the issue?

Comment: Actually I just noticed, your ms rule is positive 50% for Y, but the rest of the rules are -50% for Y. Is that causing your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct-

```
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);/*correction*/
```